# a better way to search for files remotely?

Tags: powershell

Searching for certain files types on remote servers through Powershell is excruciatingly slow.

I am using this command

```
Get-ChildItem \\servername\e$\ -recurse -Filter *.txt
```

Is there a better way to search for files remotely?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is an extremely fast solution for that which offers the results in a second. Unless you look for a GUI search. It's called *[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php)*. Give it at least a try.

When you are convinced by the ultimate speed then probably you can convince the author to provide an API for that.

If you need something effective in Powershell, then you are lost.

---

**Edit**
There is an equal tool [TFind](http://www.deadnode.org/sw/tfind/) (command line) that does the trick without an initial index. But it can't be simply used from remote. But you may to convince somebody to extend the system for remote calls.

Comment: The link goes to a tool called Everything...maybe needs edit or did you mean "Anything"?

Comment: 1. "No, 'Everything' only indexes local or removable NTFS volumes." 2. This works against an index; not the live file system. Definitely worth noting.

Comment: It needs an initial index. Then from there it is a live file system as it recognizes index changes. You don't have to use it when you say it's faster to iterate recursively through a remote folder structure...

Answer (score 1):

A much better approach would be to run the search locally on the machine that contains the files.

Comment: If both systems are Win7/Server2008R2 you can run `winrm quickconfig` on the remote system. Then run something like `invoke-command -computername remote01 -scriptblock {get-childitem ...}`

Comment: Sure - which is running a search locally on the machine that contains the files. It doesn't need to be orchestrated from that machine; that's simply where the search needs to be run.

Comment: Right, sorry if that came across strangely. Was just trying to give a concrete example of what you were proposing. That +1 you've got is from me; for giving what I would consider the "correct" answer.